# Bitwise op unexpectedly goes negative

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Can someone please explain to me why I'm getting these results?

```
public static int ipv4ToInt(String address) {
    int result = 0;

    // iterate over each octet
    for(String part : address.split(Pattern.quote("."))) {

        // shift the previously parsed bits over by 1 byte
        result = result << 8;

        System.out.printf("shift = %d\n", result);

        // set the low order bits to the current octet
        result |= Integer.parseInt(part);

        System.out.printf("result = %d\n", result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

For ipv4ToInt("10.35.41.134"), I get:

> shift = 0
>   result = 10
>   shift = 2560
>   result = 2595
>   shift = 664320
>   result = 664361
>   shift = 170076416
>   result = 170076550
>   10.35.41.134 = 170076550

This is the same result that I get when I do the math myself.

For ipv4ToInt("192.168.0.1"), I get:

> shift = 0
>   result = 192
>   shift = 49152
>   result = 49320
>   shift = 12625920
>   result = 12625920
>   shift = -1062731776
>   result = -1062731775
>   192.168.0.1 = -1062731775

For this one, when I do the math manually, I get 3232235521.

Interestingly:
3232235521 =                                 **11000000101010000000000000000001**
And when I enter 1062731775 into my Windows calc and hit the +/- button, I get:
-1062731775 = 11111111111111111111111111111111 **11000000101010000000000000000001**

The function still works for my purposes, but I'm just really curious to know why on earth result is going negative when I do that last bit shift?

Comment: That is what happens when the variable overflows. Try using a `long` instead.

Comment: Java doesn't provide an unsigned 32-bit integer. Sorry!

Comment: The top bit is set. That makes the result print as negative, but it's still the right value. You don't have to change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of bit overflow in your case!

In Java, the integer is also 32 bits and range is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

`12625920 << 8` crosses the limit of 2^31-1 and hence,the result turns negative...

The result just overturns from -ve side and hence,whatever range is left from the positive side is accompanied by that much from negative side!!!

As suggested by everyone,you should use `long` variable to avoid overflow!

Comment: Switching to long did the trick!  I know several people suggested it, so thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

All primitives in java are signed - They can be positive or negative.  The highest bit is used to control this, so when it gets set, the number becomes negative.

Try using a long instead - that will give you the wanted result, as longs can be much larger without overflow being hit.

Answer (score 1):

`11000000101010000000000000000001` is 32 bits. The value it represents depends on how you interpret those bits:

- as a 32bit signed integer, it is negative (because the left-most bit is 1)
- as a 32bit unsigned integer, it is positive (like every other unsigned integer)
- as the lowers bits of a long (signed or unsigned), it would give a positive value (if the left-most bits stay 0)

Java uses signed integers, so if you print the value, you'll see a negative number. That does not mean your bits are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It matters only for printing, you can use these ways for printing a positive integer:

1) change result to long (java will do the work for you).

2) handle signed int as unsigned int by yourself (possibly make a method int2string(int n) or toString(int n).

3) Integer.toUnsignedString(int) is you are using java 8.

As far as I understand, your are parsing an IP address, remember, java use signed data types, you can't have a 32 bits integer.

change result to long to fix that.

Comment: Why? 32 bits still fit just fine.

Comment: You only need 32 bits for 4 bytes. How you interpret the bits does not really matter until the moment you want to display the value.

Comment: yes, it fits ok, what I mean is, in order to print a positive integer there are two ways: 1) change result to long. 2) handle signed int as unsigned int by yourself.

Comment: Well, you don't say that in your answer. You should specify that it matters only for printing.

Comment: See: [`Integer.toUnsignedString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString-int-)

Comment: That's useful using java 8.